# ios animate result of background or concurrent calculations

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uikit

I do some calculations concurrently, however I want to animate the display of the results.
eg. a button is clicked, a NSInvocationOperation or an async nsnotification is posted, to perform the calculations. in the mean time the view transits to another view.
How do I animated the displaying of the calculations in the new view.

sometimes the calculations finish before the view is in the foreground (viewDidAppear) in which case the animation is not visible.

If I flag the completion of the calculations and do the animation in viewDidAppear, sometimes the calculations finish *after* viewDidAppear has been called.

What is the correct way to do this.
firing a performSelector:withObject:afterDelay: with a long delay feels like a hack begging for a race condition.

Comment: So how exactly you want it to be?

Comment: I should have explained that clicking a button, causes calculations to be performed in the background, as well as the view transitioning to another view. I want a label in the new view to animate as it displays the result.

Answer (score 0):

A state variable could accomplish this.  In your header:

```
@property BOOL viewIsVisible;
```

And in your implementation:

```
@synthesize viewIsVisible;

- (void) viewDidLoad
{
  [super viewDidLoad];
  viewIsVisible = NO;
}

- (void) viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
  [super viewDidAppear:animated];
  viewIsVisible = YES;
}

- (void) viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
  [super viewWillDisappear:animated];
  viewIsVisible = NO;
}
```

Would this work?  I'm not exactly sure how you have KVO set up.